# How to send a script path in PyDev for debugging instead of inserting settrace in the script?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev, remote-debugging

I'm following a pretty old guide where one could tell PyDev a script path from another application & it would debug it, line by line in eclipse. I like this method, instead of putting `settrace()` breakpoints in the main script.

```
scriptpath = "Users/me/Desktop/script.py"
debuggerpath = "/Users/me/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.5.0.202001101138/pysrc"

import pydev_debug as pydevd
pydevd.debug(scriptpath, debuggerpath, trace=True )
```

Most likely, the api has changed. What is the current method to do the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure which guide is this (I don't think there ever was a `pydev_debug` in PyDev).

What that module probably did is add `pydevd` to `sys.path` and then setup the current tracing in `using pydevd.settrace` and then called `execfile` (in Python 2 -- for Python 3 the exec is a bit more contrived... see: https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/blob/master/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py)

So, although there's no ready made solution for that, it should be relatively easy to do with the building blocks provided by PyDev.

Comment: It was at page 53 in the PDF book here: http://airplanes3d.net/pydev-000_e.xml. In an appendix, I found a reference to page 39 where it is suggested to put the python_debug.py file at pythonpath. See the zip for that file. Thanks a lot